# Pause HTML5 video to lighten resource load?

Tags: javascript, html, video

I have a website that has one of those annoying autoplay looping background videos that just play over and over forever instead of using just a picture. I was wondering if it would lighten the resource load on our users machines if I paused the video when they are not looking at my page through the new page visibility API?

To all the geniuses on this site, I would love to see an answer that shows how you determined your answer. I am sort of new to the front-end world and I'm not sure how I would figure this question out.

Comment: What did you try so far @stupidkid ? Please share the code you have problem with.

Answer (score 0):

@stupidkid

Though it has been asked long before, the best solution for you is here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API

```
var hidden, visibilityChange; 
if (typeof document.hidden !== "undefined") { // Opera 12.10 and Firefox 18 and later support 
  hidden = "hidden";
  visibilityChange = "visibilitychange";
} else if (typeof document.msHidden !== "undefined") {
  hidden = "msHidden";
  visibilityChange = "msvisibilitychange";
} else if (typeof document.webkitHidden !== "undefined") {
  hidden = "webkitHidden";
  visibilityChange = "webkitvisibilitychange";
}

function handleVisibilityChange() {
  if (document[hidden]) {
    //pause video
  } else {
    //play video
  }
}

document.addEventListener(visibilityChange, handleVisibilityChange, false);
```

Please try this.